# How to configure QT creator in Mint Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, linux-mint

I need to write Linux software for labs. Put on Virtual Box Mint (wrote that it is best for beginners fit). Installed QT Creator, like all the files needed downloaded. But in the end I still can not create a project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have Qt5 installed? One thing is to install Qt creator and another Qt5, could you explain how you installed them? run `qmake -v` in the console.

Comment: Could you summarize the dialog box contents for those that can't read what is in the images?

Comment: Install the dev packages of Qt lib. At least *qt5-default*, it might be enough to allow you to make widget GUI programs. Qt Creator should pick it up automatically, I think (after restart). I'd write an answer, but don't have the environment handy, so someone else hopefully writes the list of needed packages as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator is just the editor.

You still need to have at least one version of the Qt framework installed - either from an installer, built from source or from a package manager.

The installer bundles a copy (non optional) of Creator, configured to use it.

If you build from source you will have to add the Qt version (профили Qt) and make a kit (комплектьi) from it and a compatible compiler.